# Implement class method based on instance variable values (OOP)

Tags: python, class, oop

I am new to OOP. I want to create objects that have a method which depends on the instance variables value.

```py
class cases:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a  
  
    def f1(self, x):
        return x

    def f2(self, x):
        return 100*x
        
    if self.a < 3:
        self.x = f1
    else:
        self.x = f2
```

If I create the following instances `c1` and `c2` by the class `cases`:

```
c1 = cases(2)
c2 = cases(5)
```

and execute the method `x()` I expect that:

```
c1.x(10)  # --> 10
c2.x(10)  # --> 1000
```

But right now the error is:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

If I change `self.a` to just a in the class definition, the error is:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

So how can I access the variable instance for a case discrimination?

---

**UPDATE**
By following the instructions of @deceze (2nd try). Code becomes the followed:

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return 100*x

class case:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
       
    def x(self, x):
        if self.a < 3:
            return f1(x)
        else:
            return f2(x)
          
# make instances with different cases    
c1 = case(2)
c2 = case(4)

# show results
print(c1.x(10))
print(c2.x(10))
```

Result is as desired.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Firstly it looks like the `if/else` needs to be inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: Yes, that helps, but please update your question text with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana. when i put the if/else into the __init__, then f1 and f2 need to be defined previously. the full error traceback is just a NameError for 'self' or rather 'a' and i think that the example is minimal and reproducible.

Comment: actually its 2 questions in one. i will reduce it to just one question first.

Comment: Just define a method `x`, and inside `x` do your `if..else` to determine which other method to call…!?

Comment: `if self.a < 3`, `return f1(a)`…!

Comment: @deceze this is not helpful. f1 is independent of a

Comment: You want to base your condition on **`self.a`**, right? The `a` attribute you passed to the class upon instantiation. And you want `f1`/`f2` to calculate based on the value you passed to `x`. So my above suggestion is correct. It'd help if you didn't name all your variables "`a`" but used some more descriptive name somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up instances and parameters.

```py
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return 100*x



class case:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
   
    def x(self, a):
        if self.a < 3:
            return f1(a)
        else:
            return f2(a)
      
# make instances with different cases    
c1 = case(2)
c2 = case(4)

# show results
print(c1.x(10))
print(c2.x(10))
```

Output as expected.